# How to create a dynamic amount of components with React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to create a quantity x of components (TextInput), where x is the user-defined quantity. And how to store user-entered data in these inputs

Comment: `cloneElement()`?

Comment: You mean like a button that stacks up textInputs on press?

Comment: Define a new component. Pass `x` as a prop to this component. Also define an array in this component. use `useEffect` to fill this array `x` times. Then use return to render your `TextInput` components. Use a callback function on this `TextInput` compontents and fill your data in the array you have defined on your parent component.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a state like ,

```
this.state = {
arrayOfText:[]
}
```

and in the render you can achieve something like

const n = 8; // Or something else

```
[...Array(n)].map((e, i) => <TextInput className="busterCards" key={i} onChangeText={(e) => { this.setState({ arrayOfText[i]:e }) }} />)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: what is this [...Array(n)]  ?

Comment: Não está dando certo

Comment: n is the number of quantity you want that is x.